# How to create OpenVPN tunnel over existing tunnel

Tags: proxy, vpn, archlinux, openvpn

In our school we must connect to an `OpenVPN-server` to use the internet.
The problem is that many sites are locked.

Is there a possibility to create a second tunnel for connecting to a different `OpenVPN-provider` and use the second tunnel as system wide proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possibilities here:

1 Using a VM and connection one VPN on the host and one on the guest:

> Step 1 Install OpenVPN & a VirtualBox Computer
>
> Text in bold is a terminal command.
>
> First, we need to install the VPN client for Linux users. Windows users can download the > program here and here, and run the installer normally. Mac users can use this GUI for > > OpenVPN for Mac.
>
> ```
> Change to the Downloads directory.
> Configure the installation.
>     ./configure
> Compile and install.
>     make && sudo make install
> Now we need to install VirtualBox. This will allow us to have a virtual operating > > systems running from within our computer. Download VirtualBox: Windows, Mac, Linux.
> Install a virtual machine of your choice for Windows or Linux and Mac, then install > OpenVPN to it.
> ```
>
> Step 2 Chain the VPNs
>
> Start up your virtual machine, and configure them both.
>
> ```
> For Windows users using the default VPN client, use this guide to connect to a VPN. > Linux and Mac users, go here.
> Connect to VPN A with your host OS.
> Start up your virtual machine of choice, and connect to VPN B with it.
> Operate from within your virtual machine, and you will be safe from prying eyes. If > you need to delete the virtual machine, make sure you securely delete it, and your
> ```
>
> information will be safe.

Source: http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/chain-vpns-for-complete-anonymity-0131368/

2 Chaining OpenVPN and some other kind of tunnel(PPTP, SSH, etc. )

> Connect OpenVPN
>
> Connect other tunnel

Source: Brain

Comment: Your links to _Windows users can download the > program here and here_ are missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own VPN tunnel, you need, in short:

1. A server that you'll use as openVPN server
2. OpenVPN installed on your machine
3. Administrative rights on your machine
4. change the routing table so everything is routed through the second VPN, except for the IP of the first VPN and the IP of the second VPN.

for full details, you can look at my post here:
you can look at my post here:
https://www.optionull.com/2017/01/29/routing-traffic-through-openvpn-multiple-hops/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You answer looks promising, but it's usually better to include some more information directly in the answer instead of only linking, because the link may become unavailable (as is coincidentally the case for me right now).